Query to return multiple counts for each distinct item
This is my query. I know it's not correct in particular the count syntax.
SELECT DISTINCT
    product AS Type, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT c.id) AS [Total Count],
    COUNT(DISTINCT c.id = c.qDate >= '2023-06-06 00:00:00.0000000') AS [Count < One Year], 
    COUNT(DISTINCT c.id = c.qDate >= '2022-06-06 00:00:00.0000000') AS [Count < Two Year] 
FROM 
    [table1] t1
JOIN
    [table2] t2 ON t1.ID = t2.ID
JOIN 
    [table3] t3 ON t2.mb = t3.mb
WHERE 
    status IN ('P', NULL) 
GROUP BY 
    Product, c.qDate
ORDER BY
    Product

Sample of what I want my query to return:
Type        TotalCount     Count < 1 Yr    Count < 2 Yrs
--------------------------------------------------------
Van          10000           3000            7000
Car          50000          30000           70000
Truck         5000            200             500 


Make it easy to assist you, fix that horrible formatting. And a [mcve] is supposed to include both sample table data and the expected result.

And add a tag for the dbms you're using.

What's going on with your text in this question?

Replace your text with Something topsail would use

SSMS is only the UI... so not relevant to SQL questions

COUNT function is used to count non-null values, so you need to use CASE expressions within the COUNT function to achieve conditional counting. try:
SELECT 
    t1.Product AS Type,
    COUNT(DISTINCT c.id) AS [Total Count],
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN c.qDate >= '2023-06-06 00:00:00.0000000' THEN c.id END) AS [Count < One Year], 
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN c.qDate >= '2022-06-06 00:00:00.0000000' AND c.qDate < '2023-06-06 00:00:00.0000000' THEN c.id END) AS [Count < Two Year] 
FROM 
    [table1] t1
JOIN
    [table2] t2 ON t1.ID = t2.ID
JOIN 
    [table3] t3 ON t2.mb = t3.mb
WHERE 
    t1.status IN ('P', NULL) 
GROUP BY 
    t1.Product
ORDER BY
    t1.Product;


Case is an expression not a statement.

A more efficient version of the other answer would first get conditional counts for each id, then sum up for each Product. Otherwise the server thinks it needs to re-sort for each column.
Note that IN (NULL) doesn't work, as it compiles to a series of OR = clauses. You need IS NULL instead.
SELECT 
    t.Product AS Type,
    SUM(t.[Total Count]) AS [Total Count],
    SUM(t.[Count < One Year]) AS [Count < One Year],
    SUM(t.[Count < Two Year]) AS [Count < Two Year]
FROM (
    SELECT
        c.Product,
        c.id,
        COUNT(*) AS [Total Count],
        COUNT(CASE WHEN c.qDate >= '2023-06-06 00:00:00.0000000' THEN c.id END) AS [Count < One Year], 
        COUNT(CASE WHEN c.qDate >= '2022-06-06 00:00:00.0000000' AND c.qDate < '2023-06-06 00:00:00.0000000' THEN c.id END) AS [Count < Two Year] 
    FROM
        [table1] c
    JOIN
        [table2] t2 ON c.ID = t2.ID
    JOIN
        [table3] t3 ON t2.mb = t3.mb
    WHERE 
        (c.status IN ('P') OR c.status IS NULL)
    GROUP BY
        c.Product,
        c.id
) t
GROUP BY
    t.Product
ORDER BY
    t.Product;

